# Finding side of rectangle using given information

Tags: geometry

Really simple question but I am stuck. The following information is given:
$$BD=8,\quad AB = 6,\quad  ED  =5,\quad EF = EC$$
and we want to find $AF$.

If we have three $90^\circ$, what does that really mean, and how I can find $AF$? 
[image: a busy cat](') ![two muppets]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\begin{align*}
AB=6,\;BD=8,\;\text{Pythagorean theorem}&\implies AD=\mathbin{?}\\\\
ED=5&\implies AE=\mathbin{?}\\\\
EF+EC=AB=6,\;EF=EC&\implies EF=\mathbin{?}\\\\
AE=\mathbin{?},\;EF=\mathbin{?},\;\text{Pythagorean theorem}&\implies AF=\mathbin{?}\\\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I have found AE = 5 , EF = 3 , so using Pythagorean AF = 16

Comment: Almost; you forgot to take a square root.

Comment: Ohh .. then it must be 4

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way to prove this:

Since $EF+EC=6$ and $EF=EC$, this implies that $EC=3$

Notice that triangles ABD and ECD are similar in sharing a right angle, the angle at D. There is a scaling factor of 2 as $AB=6$ and $EC=3$.

Since $BC=CD$ and $BD=8$ this implies $BC=4$ as this is half the overall distance.

$AF$ is the same length as the rectangle has opposite sides of the same length.

Answer (score 1):

If you can see triangles $\widehat { AFE } $ and $\widehat { DCE } $ are the same, then everything becomes easy. Because $\widehat { AFE } $=$\widehat { AFE } $, $AF$=$CD$, because of the rectangle $AF$=$BC$, then $AF$=$BC$=$CD$. Finally $AF$=$BC$=$4$ because $BC$ is half of the $BD$.  Without math you can solve the question.

Comment: Same could be misinterpreted as congruent which they aren't since the sides aren't the same length.  They are similar triangles though I'd argue you did use some arithmetic to get the answer with a half of something computation here.